# Angular - Edit a Subject which is a type of Array

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I'm writing an application where an admin can upgrade the power of a user.

After i send the request to the server to increase a user's power. Im getting back from the server a list of users:

```
powerUp(id: number) {
return this.http
  .post<Hero[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
  .pipe(
    map((heroes) => {
      this.currentHeroes.next(hero);
    })
  );
```

}

**Here is the subject:**

```
private currentHeroes = new BehaviorSubject<Hero[]>(null);
currentHeroes$ = this.currentHeroes.asObservable();
```

The thing is that it's not officiant because I can return from the server only the particular user that is getting powered up.

```
powerUp(id: number) {
    return this.http
      .post<Hero[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
      .pipe(
        map((hero) => {
          // update the particular hero in the currentHeroes subject
        })
      );
  }
```

My question is how can I modify currentHeroes subject (only the updated user) without.next() without getting back from the server the whole list.

**I have tried to following:**

```
  powerUp(id: number) {
    return this.http
      .post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
      .pipe(
        map((updatedHero) => {
          this.currentHeroes$.pipe(
                // doesn't enter here
                map((oldHeroes) => {
                  const index = oldHeroes.findIndex((hero) => hero.id === id);
                  oldHeroes[index] = updatedHero;
                })
              );
            })
          );
      }
```

**the template of the Hero card**

```
export class HeroCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor(public heroService: HeroService, private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  powerUp(id: number, name: string) {
    this.heroService.powerUp(id).subscribe(() => {
      this.toastr.success(`${name} was successfully powered up!`);
    });
  }

  delete(id: number, name: string) {
    this.heroService.delete(id).subscribe(() => {
      this.toastr.success(`${name} was successfully deleted`);
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain me how can I manage to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the previous `currentHeroes$` and it should just work out of the box if you're using the `async` pipe.

If your template looks like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let hero of (currentHeroes$ | async)">
  <app-hero-card [hero]="hero"></app-hero-card>
</div>
```

Your component could be something as follows:

```js
@Component({…})
export class HeroListComponent {

  currentHeroes$: Observable<Hero[]>
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {
    this.currentHeroes$ = this.heroService.getHeroes()
  }

  powerUp(heroId: string) {
    this.currentHeroes$ = this.heroService.powerUp(heroId).pipe(
      switchMap(updatedHero => {
          return this.currentHeroes$.pipe(
            map(oldHeroes => {
               const index = oldHeroes.findIndex(hero => hero.id === updatedHero.id)
               oldHeroes[index]=updatedHero
               return oldHeroes
            })
          );
      })
     );
  }
}
```

And now some explanation of the magic:

1. HeroService.powerUp(heroId) will return us an observable that will emit the updated hero once the network request finishes
2. Then we transform that observable by applying the `switchMap` pipe from RxJS. What switchMap does is that it allows to say; OK whatever happens here it's going to be handled by this other observable (the one we return)
3. On the returned Observable we're just getting the old `currentHeroes$` observable and replacing the old hero by finding it by it's id and updating the array item. And finally returning the updated array

**Bonus tip**

It'd be way less code if the backend returned the updated list OR you could trigger a refetch

**If the backend returns the full list**

```js
powerUp(heroId:string) {
  this.currentHeroes$ = this.heroService.powerUp(heroId)
}
```

**If you want to trigger a refetch**

```js
powerUp(heroId:string) {
  this.currentHeroes$ = this.heroService.powerUp(heroId).pipe(
    switchMap(_updatedHero => this.heroService.getHeroes())
  );

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing explanation!!!! I have edited my question because I tried your way while slightly modifying it for my needs but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. I was wondering could you please take a look ?

Comment: I think you're missing the return statement `oldHeroes` as a last statement on the `map` operation. Otherwise it returns `undefined`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the issue

Comment: Could you share the template then?

Comment: Sure I can. But sorry for the ignorance. What template are you referring to?

Comment: I have added the template of where the powerUp happens

Comment: So for each component angular generates three files: The template (name.component.html), the component (name.component.ts) and the styles (name.component.scss). The template is where the HTML per-se is written

Comment: The issue is not in the template. The issue is that the code that I commented is unreachable for some reason. Its just skips it

Comment: It's because the operation is being performed from the child components so the parent component doesn't know when to update or what happenned. here you could work around that by using `@Output() powerUp = new EventEmitter<Hero>()` and moving the logic to the parent component